# even/uneven list items break function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this simple to-do list and am now at the point of debugging. As i am implementing different changes I've observed the following

Leaving all items on the list:
I add 1 item, no problem.
I add 2 items, nothing works - can't mark complete/incomplete.
I add 3 items, no problem. and so on

after a refresh of the page:
I add 1 item, click it, it works, delete it, make a new list with a new item, doesn't work!

Where do I begin to tackle these bugs?

https://codepen.io/HelleFl/full/EvNEgd/

```
$(function() {
  //$('input[name=checkListItem]').focus();
  $(".list-container").hide();
  $("hr").hide();
  $(".legend").hide();

  //* Prevent empty Add from continuing function by Evaluation; It will not accept only spaces; Clear input list once add is clicked; add item & Font Awesome icon to list *//
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name=checkListItem]").val().trim() !== "") {
      var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
      $(".list-container").fadeIn(500);
      $(".list").append(
        '<div class="item"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
          toAdd +
          "</div>"
      );
    }

    // Focus back on text input once add is clicked
    $("input[name=checkListItem]").val("").focus();

    // click the X icon to remove that item
    $(document).on("click", ".fa-times", function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
      if ($(".item").length === 0) {
        //If container empty, hide from view
        $(".list-container").hide();
        $("hr").fadeOut(500);
        $(".legend").fadeOut(500);
      }
    });

    // click on the item to cross it out; click it again to reactivate it
    $(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
      if ($(this).css("text-decoration").split(" ")[0] !== "line-through") {
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        $(this).css("color", "gray");
      } else {
        $(this).css("color", "");
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "");
      }
    });

    //Only show horizontal line if a list is present
    if ($(".item").length === 0) {
      $("hr").hide();
      $(".legend").hide();
    } else {
      $("hr").fadeIn(500);
      $(".legend").fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Start with creating [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a specific emphasis on *Minimal*.

Comment: I don't see any code that that saves anything (for after a page refresh).  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue revolves around the fact that you are creating new bindings every time you create a new to do action.  As you are using delegate bindings, you do not create those every time.  Pull those outside of your todo creation logic and only do them once, when the page loads.

Comment: So pull all on(click) delegates out of the creation of new items ?

Comment: Everything that does on(event, childSelector, handler) that is attached to the document should be pulled outside of any logic that repeats, so it only happens once.